# Strange error #32 on website's bottom using yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, shared-hosting

I am using yii2 , and I have recently uploaded my whole website on the godaddy shared server. I have uploaded on the root folder my all other folders like controller , vendors , config etc

Then I have uploaded my "web" folder files like index.php and themes etc to public_html folder.

Everything works fine on the server but suddenly sometime it shows at the end of my page. This randomly appear when i refresh my server I am not sure.

```
Error (#32)
An internal server error occurred.
The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.

Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.
```

This is only happens with yii2 based framework

Comment: Actually i too got this error and i was in the same godaddy shared server..... When we refresh the page it go away. This error page also appears only in the bottom.

Comment: @MohanRex are you using yii2 framework like me? Same with me when i refresh then it goes away , i could not find any solution regarding this error on internet.

Comment: Yeah @wolvorinePk Yii2-advanced template. Same here. The odd point is error appears randomly and also at bottom, which makes difficult to spot it. I think that this error appears while yii framework tries to create assets folder in web/assets directory but i'm not sure, Its just my assumption.

Comment: @MohanRex check the answer by garsim , it worked for me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you try to upgrade the php version.
I've your same error with php 5.5, but with php 5.6 everything works fine.

Comment: Dude you are awesome , what i saw was on my godaddy account it had  5.4 selected. I changed it to 5.5 since my yii2 has version in its composer written as  5.4>= . after changing that to 5.5. everything started working fine...So just anyone have this issue he must change PHP version from the Cpanel move to the greater version thats it!

Comment: My PHP version is 7.0.27. but still get same error. How to solve this?

Comment: @NcitCosmos I don't know how yii2 works with php7, in any case read the bal Singh response because it can help you more than me.

Comment: Yes, this works. I was facing the same issue and just updated my PHP version from 7.4 to 7.3.

Answer (score 2):

I have also got same error, when I check error_log file, I found a php error like,
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/timezonedb.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/timezonedb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0.

I think you may have some php library error in your shared hosting. So check your error_log file. It will helpfull to debugg error.