# Yii2 Error #32 - Any Ideas What This Might Be?

Tags: php, yii2

I just rolled out my Yii2 advanced template to AWS and now all of a sudden I'm getting intermittent Error #32 errors.

I've read the previous comments here: [Strange error #32 on website's bottom using yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285538/strange-error-32-on-websites-bottom-using-yii2/31547984?noredirect=1#comment51059332_31547984)

But I'm running PHP 5.6.10 so that can't be it.  Does anyone have any ideas what might be the problem?  Also I'm not seeing any errors in my log files either.

Comment: Have you check error log in apache as well ?

Comment: Turn on the `debug` on and see what is the error! Probably it will be a `register_long_arrays` issue.

Comment: Yes I've checked the error logs but don't see any errors.

Comment: Also check what the `requirements.php` file is outputting, as **error #32** is a **PHP Core Warning**, maybe it is about a missing library or other server configuration issue. If not from server configs & nothing to get from your server errors log files or yii's debug files, and you are using the last stable release (Yii 2.0.5 at this writing time) then I think it will better if you report that issue to their [Github repository](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2)

Comment: Yes I have checked the requirement that is being output.  What is even more odd is that as soon as I turned on debug YII_DEBUG the issue goes away so there's definitely something wrong with the default Yii configuration .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some further analysis it turns out that my environment was loading the ImageMagick module twice.  So after fixing that the problem went away.

Thanks though for your thoughtful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If the error  is intermitting check in  your enviroment if APC is enable and try disabling it. I have experienced a nintermitting internal error and analysing debug information are due to an non optimal cache mamangement, disabling the APC extension all work fine (and fast)